# Vue Storefront Returns Something went wrong

Tags: magento2

Hi am trying to setup vuestorefront locally over windows 10 and it compiled successfully but on frontend it showing something went wrong

**Something went wrong ...
We've noticed Internal Server Error while rendering this request.
If you need an assistance you can drop us a line on a contact page**

**also am getting this error in console**

```
{"code":500,"result":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request [/vue_storefront_catalog/attribute/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [_source_include] -> did you mean any of [_source_includes, _source_excludes]?"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request [/vue_storefront_catalog/attribute/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [_source_include] -> did you mean any of [_source_includes, _source_excludes]?"}}
```

searchAdapter.ts:78 GET http://localhost:8080/api/catalog/vue_storefront_catalog/attribute/_search?_source_include=activity%2Cattribute_code%2Cattribute_id%2Cdefault_frontend_label%2Cdefault_value%2Centity_type_id%2Cfrontend_input%2Cfrontend_label%2Cid%2Cis_user_defined%2Cis_visible_on_front%2Cis_visible%2Cis_comparable%2Coptions%2Ctier_prices&from=0&request=%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%22bool%22%3A%7B%22filter%22%3A%7B%22terms%22%3A%7B%22attribute_code%22%3A%5B%22color%22%2C%22erin_recommends%22%2C%22price%22%2C%22size%22%2C%22activity%22%2C%22final_price%22%2C%22id%22%2C%22image%22%2C%22name%22%2C%22new%22%2C%22original_price%22%2C%22original_price_incl_tax%22%2C%22price_incl_tax%22%2C%22product_links%22%2C%22sale%22%2C%22sku%22%2C%22special_price%22%2C%22special_price_incl_tax%22%2C%22special_from_date%22%2C%22special_to_date%22%2C%22status%22%2C%22tax_class_id%22%2C%22tier_prices%22%2C%22type_id%22%2C%22url_path%22%2C%22url_key%22%5D%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D&size=150&sort= 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide essential details. Fortunately, I know what's wrong.

You've configured your application to use a different version of Elasticsearch than you installed. E.g. you configured it to use 5.6 version but you installed version 7.x.

In 6 or 7 version of Elasticsearch there were breaking changes - one of them is change the name of `_source_include` property to the `_source_includes`.

Just after you unify version & configuration. It will work fine.